# Multiple request model based on path param in Swagger | Spring

Tags: spring, spring-boot, swagger, swagger-ui, swagger-2.0

I have a rest controller, where I am accepting the request body into a string. And then based on type in path param, transforming stringify request body into the corresponding model.

Example endpoint: /xyz/123/{type}

Let's say, the type could be A, B, C, and their corresponding models would be AModel.class, BModel.class, CModel.class.

The question is how can I expose this endpoint in the nicer way in swagger documentation. Looking for some easy and extensible way. I am using spring-fox, would be great if I don't have to write the swagger file explicitly.

I am using spring boot project. Explored a lot of link, but couldn't find thing I am looking for.

Thanks.